# MySQL function user context

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a MySql stored function that will return the username of the currently connected user. When I connect as user 'x' to the database, it still returns the username 'root'.

Why is this and how do i get it to return the username 'x' from the function.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetUserName`() RETURNS char(255) CHARSET utf8
BEGIN

RETURN cast( SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(),'@',1) as char(255) );
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there is are two options, SQL SECURITY INVOKER and SQL SECURITY DEFINER described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-security.html)
Switching to SQL SECURITY INVOKER fixed it.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetUserName`() RETURNS char(255) CHARSET utf8
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

RETURN cast( SUBSTRING_INDEX(CURRENT_USER(),'@',1) as char(255) );
END
```